# Are there any differences between "we must hurry" and "we must be hurried" or do they have the same meaning

Tags: difference, phrase-meaning, modal-verbs, passive-voice

When I continued to watch the quotes of Castelvania, I found that the use of the verb, hurry made me very confused:

> Stella: And Miss Charlotte, thank you so much for setting us
>           free.
>
> Charlotte: Sure thing. The curse may be lifted, but you should
>              still take it easy.
>
> Loretta: But...
>
> Stella: We already know. **Anyway, we must hurry**. We must defeat
>           Brauner. The piece he's making now is meant to destroy the
>           world!

Can you explain why it is "we must hurry", but not "we must be hurried".
As far as I know, there was something that made them hurry,
so it would be more easy for me to understand if they wrote "Anyway, we must be hurried" in the quote.   Or I am wrong about their difference?

Thank you.

I am so happy that I have learnt how to use the Quote function here.  This was my first time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Anyway, we must hurry.

...uses the active voice. The meaning is "Anyway, we have an obligation to act faster".

Some considerations made Stella think that she and her friends are under a [moral obligation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontic_modality) to act faster.

---

> Anyway, we must be hurried.

...uses the passive voice. The sentence would mean "Someone must hurry us". Someone must induce us to act faster.

This construction would not work here. Generally speaking, **hurry** is not very often used in the passive voice, and when it is used, it seems to assume meanings different from "someone made him hurry":

> *We had many sick in the hospital, for when anyone appeared to be disordered in the least degree, **he was hurried** to the infirmary, when cured, he was returned to us.*  ([Google Books, 1813](https://books.google.ru/books?id=wdJEAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22he%20was%20hurried%22&hl=ru&pg=PA137#v=onepage&q=%22he%20was%20hurried%22&f=false)) --

The meaning is "He was quickly *transported* to the hospital *by some people's efforts*." Clearly nobody *forced* the ill guy to run to the hospital.

---

P.S. A Google search for **we must be hurried** returned less than a dozen results! The best example has the same meaning of *being quickly transported*:

> We **must be hurried forward** from one situation to another; and unlooked-for events, and frequent changes must occur. ([1837](https://books.google.ru/books?id=hvheAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PA197&ots=6rbqaisWpm&dq=%22we%20must%20be%20hurried%22&hl=ru&pg=PA197#v=onepage&q=%22we%20must%20be%20hurried%22&f=false))

The author describes how a book, a work of fiction, must *transport* the reader quckly from one situation to another - not to *force* the reader to read faster, but to "carry him" from page to page smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

The verb hurry is both a transitive and intransitive verb.

We must hurry.

The verb has been used as an intransitive verb.  The sentence means that it's necessary for us to move or act quickly.

We must be hurried.

The verb  has been used as a transitive verb.

The sentence  that's in the passive possibly has two meanings - the first is that it's necessary that somebody cause us to move or act quickly, and the second is that it's necessary that somebody carry/take us quickly (to a place).

In light of these different meanings of the two sentences, I think it's clear that the sense of the first sentence fits well in the context.

Comment: +1 for the mention of transitive vs. intransitive senses of **hurry**.